# React Native: Getting Failed to notify project evaluation listener when bumping to 0.72

Tags: android, react-native, mobile-development

We are facing this issue when bumping React Native from 0.65.2 from 0.72.6

Gradle: 7.5.1 (8.0.1 was failing due to some deprecated Transform methods)

Error log

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > 'com.android.build.api.component.impl.ComponentPropertiesImpl com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ComponentInfo.getProperties()'
   > 'com.android.build.api.component.impl.ComponentPropertiesImpl com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ComponentInfo.getProperties()'
```

Was able to get this from stacktrace

```
Cause 1: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.android.build.api.component.impl.ComponentPropertiesImpl com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ComponentInfo.getProperties()'
        at com.archinamon.utils.VariantUtilsKt.getVariantDataList(VariantUtils.kt:102)
        at com.archinamon.plugin.PluginSetupKt.prepareVariant(PluginSetup.kt:53)
        at com.archinamon.plugin.PluginSetupKt.access$prepareVariant(PluginSetup.kt:1)
        at com.archinamon.plugin.PluginSetupKt$configProject$1.invoke(PluginSetup.kt:28)
        at com.archinamon.plugin.PluginSetupKt$configProject$1.invoke(PluginSetup.kt)
        at com.archinamon.plugin.PluginSetupKt$whenEvaluated$1.execute(PluginSetup.kt:126)
        at com.archinamon.plugin.PluginSetupKt$whenEvaluated$1.execute(PluginSetup.kt)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:123)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:171)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:168)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:95)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:245)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:346)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:249)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:141)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
```

Not able to comprehend where it was used and if its react native core related or stems from other packages. Any clue would help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by an older version of Instana React Native package. Bumped to `2.0.0` to get it resolved.
https://npmjs.com/package/@instana/react-native-agent